# Referencing sheets in Apache POI Formulas

Tags: java, excel, excel-2003, formula, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI 3.6 to generate excel (2003) sheets. I want to insert a formula to a cell which calculates a sum of a certain cells on several sheets.

I have sheets named a, b and c and want to calculate the sum the cells A1

I tried:

```
cell.setCellFormula("a!A1+b!A1+c!A1");
```

POI does not produce any errors, but when I open the sheet I get an error in OpenOffice:

```
Err: 522 - =$#REF!.A1+$#REF!.A1+$#REF!.A1
```

I did a bit of research and apparently there are bugs when referencing multiple sheets. (eg https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46670) Does anyone have an idea how to use formulas using multiple sheets in POI?

-------------- source code -------------------

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Total");

    Row row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

    cell.setCellFormula("a!A1+b!A1+c!A1");

    Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("a");
    Sheet sheet2 = wb.createSheet("b");
    Sheet sheet3 = wb.createSheet("c");
    Sheet sheet4 = wb.createSheet("d");

    createVal(sheet1, createHelper, 5);
    createVal(sheet2, createHelper, 10);
    createVal(sheet3, createHelper, 15);
    createVal(sheet4, createHelper, 20);

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.println("done");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   }

public static void createVal(Sheet sheet, CreationHelper createHelper, int i){
     Row row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
        // Create a cell and put a value in it.
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        // Or do it on one line.
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue(i);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code will work fine if you move the creaton of "Total" sheet to **after** populating the individual sheets.

Like below:

```
...    
    createVal(sheet1, createHelper, 5); 
    createVal(sheet2, createHelper, 10); 
    createVal(sheet3, createHelper, 15);
    createVal(sheet4, createHelper, 20); 

    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Total"); 
    Row row = sheet.createRow((short)0); 
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0); 

    cell.setCellFormula("a!A1+b!A1+c!A1");
```

Cell `Total!A1` shows `30`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works completely fine

Comment: As per MS Excel, i was putting '.' in place of '!'. Thanks